# Can you drag and drop to create a graph in python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, visualization

Is it possible to create a graph by drag and drop from a dataset/dataframe in python? I'm interested in creating a tableau like interface where once I upload a dataset/dataframe, I can simply create a graph by dragging and dropping a column. And that's it; not looking for any other tableau like features, only the drag drop to create graph.

I do have a experimental version going, but it uses ipywidgets dropdown. It works, but it's quite funky, and I really want to use the drag and drop. Is there anyway to achieve that?

P.S. I'm coding on google colab and this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, HTML

df = [import/insert dataframe/dataset path]

# Set the maximum number of displayed rows
pd.options.display.max_rows = None  # Display all rows

# Create dropdown
platform_dropdown2 = widgets.Dropdown(options=df.columns, description='Select Column:')
value_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(description='Select Value')
sort_column_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=df.columns, description='Sort By Column:')
sort_order_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Ascending', 'Descending'], description='Sort Order:')
search_text = widgets.Text(placeholder='Search...', description='Search:')
apply_button = widgets.Button(description='Apply Filters')
loading_icon = widgets.HTML(value='')

output = widgets.Output()

def update_value_dropdown(change):
    selected_column = platform_dropdown2.value

    # Set unique_values alphabetically sorted
    unique_values = sorted(df[selected_column].unique())

    # Add '-' to the beginning of unique_values
    unique_values = ['-'] + unique_values

    # Set the selected value as the default option in the value dropdown
    selected_value = value_dropdown.value if value_dropdown.value in unique_values else '-'

    value_dropdown.options = unique_values
    value_dropdown.value = selected_value

def apply_filters(b):
    with output:
        output.clear_output()
        display(loading_icon)

        selected_column = platform_dropdown2.value
        selected_value = value_dropdown.value
        selected_sort_order = sort_order_dropdown.value
        selected_sort_column = sort_column_dropdown.value

        filtered_data = df.copy()  # Make a copy of the original data

        if selected_value != '-':  # If a value is selected and not '-', apply the value filter
            filtered_data = filtered_data[filtered_data[selected_column] == selected_value]

        if selected_sort_column != '-':  # If a sort column is selected and not '-', apply sorting
            sorted_data = filtered_data.sort_values(by=selected_sort_column, ascending=(selected_sort_order == 'Ascending'))
        else:
            sorted_data = filtered_data.copy()

        # Reorder columns based on the sorting column
        if selected_sort_column != '-':
            sorted_columns = [selected_sort_column] + [col for col in sorted_data.columns if col != selected_sort_column]
            sorted_data = sorted_data[sorted_columns]

        # Reorder columns to have the selected column as the first column
        sorted_data = sorted_data[[selected_column] + [col for col in sorted_columns if col != selected_column]]

        # Apply search filter
        search_term = search_text.value.lower()  # Convert search term to lowercase
        if search_term:
            filtered_data = sorted_data.apply(lambda row: row.str.lower().str.contains(search_term).any(), axis=1)
            sorted_data = sorted_data[filtered_data]

        loading_icon.value = '<div class="loader"></div>'
        output.clear_output()

        with output:
            display(sorted_data)
            loading_icon.value = ''

platform_dropdown2.observe(update_value_dropdown, names='value')
apply_button.on_click(apply_filters)

info = widgets.VBox([platform_dropdown2, value_dropdown, sort_column_dropdown, sort_order_dropdown, search_text, apply_button, loading_icon, output])

display(info)

# Styling for the loading icon
display(HTML("""
<style>
.loader {
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
"""))
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create graphs in Python using various libraries, and some of these libraries offer a drag-and-drop interface for graph creation within their graphical user interfaces (GUIs). One of the popular libraries for creating graphs in Python is `matplotlib`, and there are GUI tools that use `matplotlib` for graphing. One such tool is "matplotlib.pyplot" in Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab, which provides a simple way to create graphs using a combination of code and a drag-and-drop interface.

Here's a simple example of creating a graph using the "matplotlib.pyplot" library in a Jupyter Notebook:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [10, 25, 18, 30, 15]

# Create a line plot using drag-and-drop interface
plt.plot(x, y)

# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Sample Line Plot')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

In this example, you can create a line plot by dragging and dropping the necessary components within a Jupyter Notebook cell.

Keep in mind that while you can use GUI tools for some level of interactivity and convenience, more complex graphs might still require manual coding to achieve specific customization or advanced features. Additionally, there might be other libraries and tools that provide more advanced drag-and-drop capabilities for graph creation.

If you're looking for more interactive and drag-and-drop-based graphing, you might also consider using tools like Tableau or Plotly, which have Python libraries and interfaces for creating interactive visualizations with less manual coding.

Comment: As far as I know, drag and drop is not possible with Matplotlib and Jupyter. Please provide some documentation links to back things up.